# How to load a view with a parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Sorry in advance if this has been asked before, but I can't find what I am looking for.

I have an ASP.NET MVC app with Angular.JS

I have a normal list of resources on one page and when I click an Action Link, I want to display a separate View which calls the api controller with the id to populate that page. Simple right?

I have the link on the first page defined like this:

```
<a data-ng-href="@Url.Action("EditResource", "Home")/{{items.Resource.ResourceId}}">{{items.Resource.ResourceId}}</a>
```

The Home controller is a simple Controller.

My View starts off with these Angular directives:

```
<div ng-app="productSkillsApp" id="body">
<div ng-controller="editResourceCtrl">
```

Then in my javascript I have this:

```
app.controller('editResourceCtrl', function ($scope, $http, SkillsService) {
    $scope.resourceData = null;
    // Fetching records from the factory
    SkillsService.GetAllProductSkills().then(function (d) {
        $scope.resourceData = d.data; // Success
    }, function () {
        alert('Error Occured !!!'); // Failed
    });
});

// Dependency injection
app.factory('SkillsService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetAllRecords = function () {
        return $http.get('api/Skills/GetAllSkills');
    }
    fac.GetAllProductSkills = function () {
        return $http.get('api/Skills/GetAllResourceProductSkills');
    }
    return fac;
});
```

This is the same call that the first page calls, but it fails here.

So my other questions are:
1) Can a Controller call an ApiController?
2) How does the id get passed to a javascript function call?
3) What else am I missing? You don't know what you don't know!

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't using an angular router and think that is what you are looking for. Not entirely clear what you are asking

Comment: We need to see more code here... `function (id) {  return $http.get('api/Skills/GetAllResourceProductSkills/' + id); }` would append an ID to your call..

Comment: Part of the solution was to simply add '/' to the api call since it was appending to the view.

$http.get('/api/Skills/GetResourceProductSkills');

But now I do not know how to pass the id from the query string.
It is not in $http like I expect.

Comment: See [AngularJS ngRoute API Reference - Examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#examples). Look at the path `/Book/Moby/ch/1` to see how it is done.

Comment: Since you are using Angular 1, I would recommend looking into UI-Router, with is a Router that requires you to define a state tree. Each state can be designated a controller and template (essentially a pre-cursor to Component-based architecture). UI Router provides a directive `ui-sref` that allows you to navigate to named states passing in parameters and query arguments as objects. UI Router addresses many short-comings of the ngRouter packaged with Angular 1, and is in many applications requiring more than one named-view. The Angular 2 ngRouter is improved and recommend for Angular2+ apps.